# What syntax do I need to get a C# generic property accessor method to have the same name as its type?

Tags: c#, generics, properties, accessor

In C# I like to implement property get/set methods whose *name* is the same as the name of the returned/applied *type*. This suits me as it means I don't have to devise my own new name for the method. For instance:

```
class MyClass
{
    public XmlDocument XmlDocument { get; set: }
    ...
```

My question is - how would I express the above when `MyClass` is a Generic class? I've tried this:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public T T { get; set; }
    ...
```

But the C# compiler raises an error:

> Error CS0102  The type 'MyClass' already contains a definition for
>   'T'

I also tried `nameof(T)` and `@T` to specify the name of the method, but they raised different compiler errors.

Is what I want to do even possible?  If it is, what syntax should I use for the name of the property accessor?

Comment: Why exactly is it that you want to do this? Calling c# Generics "templates" sounds like you are thinking in C/C++

Comment: I've tried to correct the question, changing "template" into "generic"

Comment: I still want to know why you want to do this, because it doesn't make sense just from your question

Comment: I wanted to make a bundle of related objects and thought if I declared Bundle<S,T,U> I could construct a Bundle by passing in S, T and U and then have property accessors to get each type. But the list of bundled types changes which is why I wanted a list of types. I tried using a tuple but didn't like the way the fields were referred to as item1 item2 etc. So I was looking for some nice lightweight way to bundle related objects together.

Comment: Have you looked at (and can use) named Tuples? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Many thanks for the suggestion. It looks as though each time I use a tuple I'd have to include its definition (if I'm reading the C# tuples MSDN page correctly). Is there a way of declaring a tuple _type_ and then using that throughout my code?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from using something as `public class MyClass : Tuple<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>` (but I wouldn't use a `Tuple` for that, I'd just use a normal class..) that's the only way I know of

Comment: What you want is not possible in Code, but like others mentioned, in T4-template. You could use a dynamic, mimic this behavior though. I don’t know, if you’re familiar with dynamic, nor if you want to use it, so if you need help...ask.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to base name of generics method/property on type specified as argument.

You can generate such classes using templating (like t4) or code at run-time.

Notes:

- if that would be possible it would be very hard to use such generic type as method names would not be known at compile time or again depend on type at hand
- it is generally cause a lot of confusion when property names are the same as types...

Comment: "it is generally cause a lot of confusion when property names are the same as types... " Not really, anyone that has used EF for some time is extremely used to this, since by default a navigation property's name is the name of the type